# $X\stackrel{d}{=}E[X|\mathcal{G}]\implies X=E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ a.s.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, self-learning, conditional-expectation

> Let $X\in L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ and let $\mathcal{G}\subset\mathcal{A}$ be a sub $\sigma$-algebra. Assume that $X\stackrel{d}{=}E[X|\mathcal{G}].$ Prove that $X=E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ a.s.

I have posted and solved a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3729006/show-that-if-exg-le-x-a-s-then-x-exg-a-s) but I cannot figure out how to make the necessary changes from the assumption that $E[X|\mathcal{G}]\le X$ a.s. to the assumption that $X\stackrel{d}{=}E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ in order to alter this proof to make it work. Any help with that or a full blown new proof would be greatly appreciated.